# Javascript function in external file won't populate inputs with its values in MVC view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have been debugging for a couple hours now and still running into an issue with taking the data from javascript function that is in an external file and populating inputs with the data that is in the function. I had asked a similar question a couple hours ago but I think I gave to much information and didn't ask the correct question.

I have about 16 html text inputs, and as I am debugging I see that values in the external file, but they don't want to get put into the html text inputs, I have no idea why either.
I have double checked and made sure that I am using the correct id's for the textboxes and I they are all correct, and just to make sure that they were correct, I cut and pasted the id's.

here is my javascript function

```
    function ClientDataToGet(clientInfoData) {
    $("#txtCompanyName").val(clientInfoData[0].companyName);
    $("#txtAddress1").val(clientInfoData[0].address);
    $("#txtAddress2").val(clientInfoData[0].address2);
    $("#txtCity").val(clientInfoData[0].city);
    $("#txtState").val(clientInfoData[0].state);
    $("#txtZip").val(clientInfoData[0].zip);
    $("#txtEmail").val(clientInfoData[0].email);
    $("#txtContact").val(clientInfoData[0].contactName);
    $("#txtPhone").val(clientInfoData[0].phone);
    $("#txtWorkPhone").val(clientInfoData[0].work);
    $("#txtMobile").val(clientInfoData[0].mobile);
    $("#txtFax").val(clientInfoData[0].fax);
    $("#txtOther").val(clientInfoData[0].other);
}
```

any idea on what I am doing wrong? I have something similar to this in a view that isn't using an external file and its working perfectly fine.

**EDIT**
[image: Whats in the ClientDataToGet]

Comment: The above code is not enough to tell what's happening.. you need to show how you are getting values to `clientInfoData` from external file

Comment: there might be a problem referencing the external file.

Comment: can you proveide the sample data that you are getting in the parameter `clientInfoData` ?

Comment: What does say `console.log(clientInfoData[0].companyName);` return?

Comment: @JSantosh, I'll take a screen shot of it and post the data that ClientInfoData has

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Hi Stephen, you were around for my last question about this...I'll take a couple scren shots and show what I am gettting

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I am getting an error in the console...Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'companyName' of undefined, I thought maybe I should capitalize the first letters as they are in the screen shot I just added, but that gave me the same error

Comment: @JSantosh, screen shot is added

Comment: Because your controller method is passing a single object, not a collection of objects - it needs to be `$("#txtAddress1").val(clientInfoData.address);` etc (no indexer)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clientInfoData is an object not an Array. so dont use `clientInfoData[0].companyName`. Use this `clientInfoData.companyName`

Answer (score 0):

could you please share ClientInfoData object also please

try this

```
function ClientDataToGet(clientInfoData) {
    $("#txtCompanyName").val(clientInfoData.companyName);
    $("#txtAddress1").val(clientInfoData.address);
    $("#txtAddress2").val(clientInfoData.address2);
    $("#txtCity").val(clientInfoData.city);
    $("#txtState").val(clientInfoData.state);
    $("#txtZip").val(clientInfoData.zip);
    $("#txtEmail").val(clientInfoData.email);
    $("#txtContact").val(clientInfoData.contactName);
    $("#txtPhone").val(clientInfoData.phone);
    $("#txtWorkPhone").val(clientInfoData.work);
    $("#txtMobile").val(clientInfoData.mobile);
    $("#txtFax").val(clientInfoData.fax);
    $("#txtOther").val(clientInfoData.other);
}
```